# Invalid scope on Instagram API app before it is reviewed

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to develop a site that connects to META's Instagram API. I have an app in development mode, and when a test user tries to connect, we get this error:

> Invalid Request: Request parameters are invalid: Invalid scope: instagram_content_publish

Research shows that that feature is not allowed until we have completed app review. However, META's app review requires that we show a video of the feature working.

So how are we supposed to get a video of the feature working if we can't get it working until we have app review completed?